# Material UI modal not refreshing after async call

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I'm using Material UI dialog and I'm seeing really strange behavior.

When I open the `Dialog` on a mobile or tablet the first time, I can't see the image. However, when I close the dialog and upon it, I can see the image.

It's behaving the same on all devices. I've had a look at the network tab on Chrome and I can see the images already downloaded. So it doesn't make sense why it displays the only after opening it twice

Is there a reason this is happening?

This is what my code looks like:

```
import { Dialog, CardMedia } from "@material-ui/core";

export default ({ open, handleClose }) => {
  const theme = useTheme();
  const fullScreen = useMediaQuery(theme.breakpoints.down("md"));

  return (
    <Dialog
      fullWidth
      maxWidth="lg"
      fullScreen={fullScreen}
      open={open}
      TransitionComponent={Transition}
      onClose={handleClose}
      aria-labelledby="responsive-dialog-title"
    >
        <CardMedia
          style={{height: 0, paddingTop: "56.25%"}}
          image="https://source.unsplash.com/random"
          title={competition.title}
        />
    </Dialog>
  );
};
```

Comment: It is possible that at the image might be arriving slowly on mobile devices as compared to desktop.

Comment: I've also managed to replicate it locally. It's behaving the same i.e on first opening the dialog, it doesn't show the image and in second try it displays the image.

Comment: Please reproduce the behavior in a [code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/new).